# discordbot code error with coinflip command javascript

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I'm pretty new to coding, and I'm trying to code a discord bot to flip a coin. I have edited and rewritten my code several times, and still can't get it to work.

Here's what I'm working with currently:

```
if (command === 'ht'){
        function doRandHT() {
            var rand = ['HEADS!','TAILS!'];
            return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0) ? 'heads' : 'tails';
        }
        execute(message, args, Discord); {
            const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            "title"; ('Here is the winner!'),
            "description"; doRandHT(),
            "color"; 7584788,
            message.channel.send({ embed });
        }
```

I'm sure it's something obvious but I just can't get it to work, what should I fix?

Comment: What is your issue exactly ? Please [edit] your question :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all the you make newembed a variable but never use it so you basically send nothing in the channel

second of all the way you make your embed is wrong, check out [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor) on how to do it

so the working way of your code would be:

```
if (command === 'ht'){
    function doRandHT() {
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0) ? 'HEADS!' : 'TAILS!';
    }
execute(message); {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Here is the winner!`)
    .setDescription(doRandHT())
    .setColor("#73BC14")
    message.channel.send(embed)
   }
}
```

Comment: ah, thanks for the help, now I'm getting a "MessageEmbed is not defined" error lol, any idea what it could be? I edited my code based on what you provided

Comment: oh fixed that issue for you, copy the code again :D

Comment: Ah thanks!! I was stuggling for a while